# Determining which visual style is used?

Tags: winapi, visual-styles

Is there a method to determine which visual style (Classic, "XP Style", Aero, etc') is currently used? App is native, so .net solutions are out.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that >99% of users won't change it. XP users will use XP style, etc.

Comment: Nope, I think it's not safe to assume so. Every even slightly advanced user tends to customize their system heavily.

Comment: Why do you need that? Is it to draw some element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetCurrentThemeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773365(VS.85).aspx) (IsThemeActive or IsAppThemed tells you if visual styles are on)